# Transferring data from one page to another windows 8 phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to transfer data from one page to another with a windows phone app I'm creating. I'm getting the error Error 1   The name 'enterNameBox' does not exist in the current context
Can someone tell me what I did wrong?
First Page(getStartedButton takes you to other page)
[code]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using FinalProjectPhoneVersion.Resources;

namespace FinalProjectPhoneVersion
{

    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        static int strikeCounter;
        static int counter;
        static Random random = new Random();

        static int randomNumber1;
        static int randomNumber2;

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }

        // Sample code for building a localized ApplicationBar
        //private void BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
        //{
        //    // Set the page's ApplicationBar to a new instance of ApplicationBar.
        //    ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

        //    // Create a new button and set the text value to the localized string from AppResources.
        //    ApplicationBarIconButton appBarButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/appbar.add.rest.png", UriKind.Relative));
        //    appBarButton.Text = AppResources.AppBarButtonText;
        //    ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(appBarButton);

        //    // Create a new menu item with the localized string from AppResources.
        //    ApplicationBarMenuItem appBarMenuItem = new ApplicationBarMenuItem(AppResources.AppBarMenuItemText);
        //    ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(appBarMenuItem);
        //}
        public MathPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        String welcomeString = (String)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["enterNameBox"];
        RadioButton easyMode = (RadioButton)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["easyMode"];
        RadioButton hardMode = (RadioButton)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["hardMode"];
        welcomeLabel.Text = "Welcome " + welcomeString;
       if (easyMode.Checked = true) { 

        }
    }

        private void getStartedButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MathTime();
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?enterNameBox=test", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }


    }
```

[/code]

Second Page
[code]

```
     using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;

namespace FinalProjectPhoneVersion
{
    public partial class MathPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public MathPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            welcomeLabel.Text = "Welcome " + enterNameBox.Text;
        }

        private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            string parameterValue = NavigationContext.QueryString["enterNameBox"];
        }
    }
}
```

[/code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using Phone Application Service instead to save values between pages.

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["id_of_value"] = value;
```

First page

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["enterNameBox"] = "test"
```

Second page

```
String my_string = (String) PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["enterNameBox"];
```

More information can be found here [How to preserve and restore app state for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff967547(v=vs.105).aspx)

Edit:
Was in the middle of answering your radio button comment but looks like you deleted it.  It should work for most types.

First Page

```
 PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["radio_button1"] = this.your_radio_button;
```

Second Page

```
 RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["radio_button1"];
 rb.IsChecked = true; // or false
```

When you press the Back button, your Radio button will update itself as well.

Comment: Your code works fine, but if I try and use it in an if statement it throws an error How can I use this with an if statement. I'm surprise it doesn't work?  if (rb.IsChecked = true)
            {

            } Error:Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?

Comment: Yeah I know of that.  Try if((bool)rb.IsChecked == true)

Comment: And for good measure here's the documentation for "bool?" conversion: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384091.aspx